# How make form registration with collect data from google using laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, google-api, laravel-5.3

I Want to make the registration form using personal data from google, how to integrate with laravel 5.3?

Comment: You are basically trying to use socialite. Here is the package: https://github.com/laravel/socialite. Next time, google before asking questions here. Your question is going to be downvoted because you showed no effort of trying.

Comment: @eddy. im sorry, i already reading in some article but there is no matching with my case. ok thanks before

Comment: What is your case ?

Comment: @eddy, i want form registration autofill after click button google registration, not login using google authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socialite does not authenticate users for you. It gives you user information. That's  it. In your controller, do this:

```
$user = Socialite::with($provider)->user();
```

Then pass the `$user` variable to your view

```
return view('view', compact('user'));
```

In your view, check if the `$user` variable exists, if so, prefill the registration form. Like this:

```
<input name="email" type="email" value="{{ $user ? $user->getEmail() : $user}}"/>
```

That's it. You have all the user's info in your form.

Comment: i got error in installing socialite,

"  Problem 1
    - laravel/socialite v3.0.0 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v5.4.0].
    - laravel/socialite v3.0.2 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v5.4.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/http v5.4.0
    - Installation request for laravel/socialite ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v3.0.0, v3.0.2]. "

Comment: You Laravel 5.4. What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: thank you very much, i can using google api and successfull through javascript like the google document https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Answer (score 0):

in login form using entrust and filtering active user, but i want login as usual not using google API authentication. in many articles socialite package be used login form, i want socialite for registration....

ilustration:

1. step 1: i'm open registration form.
2. step 2: in page registration form be found 2 option, the first manual registration in form regisration, the second click button google for registration.
3. step 3 : form registration automatically filled corresponding personal data google.